# Find out hit count using ajax & javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, hit

We have a page which has the option to add websites. The application should create a JavaScript code which we could include in a website which would cause hits to the other websites added in the application when a user visit a parent website.

For example, as a first step you can create the code like adding an Ajax call (if the website is https://www.google.co.in/)

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $.post('https://www.google.co.in/', function(data) {

    });
  });
</script>
```

If the user add next site 2 there should be an Ajax call to both sites. When the user adds a site, show the code in an area from there the user can copy it.

Comment: "Cause hits"? Are you trying to write a tool to artificially inflate advert views?

Comment: 1. All your sires must Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* header. 2. Its better to generate a generic method which would in turn provide links to other pages and this page list can be returned via an API

Comment: @Nakshathra Please explain the "..cause hits.." sentece. Do you mean to send a post to your server so you can monitor hit count?

Comment: @Quentin Read the title of the question, he/she is obviously trying to gauge hits..

Comment: @hitautodestruct — Read the history of the question. The title has changed since that comment was made.

Comment: @Quentin Right, should be flagged then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get around Access-Control-Allow-Origin using JavaScript you can insert an iframe on to the page with the source being the URL for the new websites added to the page including any parameters. When the iframe is inserted the request will be made to the target site. Note that these will be GET and NOT POST requests.